# UITextView can't show svg with image tag

Tags: image, svg, uitextview

I want to show a html with UITextView,but the svg image can't be displayed,
Can anyone help me? below is my html:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"><head><meta content="true" name="calibre:cover"/><title>Cover</title><style type="text/css">
@page {padding: 0pt; margin:0pt}
            body { text-align: center; padding:0pt; margin: 0pt; }
</style></head><body><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 600 800" width="100%"><image height="800" width="600" xlink:href="file:///var/mobile/Applications/E450E9B5-A298-4912-BF3F-FBDE9D655B34/Library/Caches/UnzippedEpub/812CDAD1-30BF-454D-A3AD-6C24E06DEED8/OEBPS/Images/cover.jpeg"/></svg></body></html>
```

Comment: This is not your URL, this is the DOCTYPE declaration for your XHTML 1.1 formated document.

Comment: May be the problem is the local file "file:///var/mobile/Applications/E450E9B5-A298-4912-BF3F-FBDE9D655B34/Library/Caches/UnzippedEpub/812CDAD1-30BF-454D-A3AD-6C24E06DEED8/OEBPS/Images/cover.jpeg" Security restrictions? Is <SVG> tag really part of XHTML 1.1?